# how can i get the total from the four different table in single query

Tags: mysql, sum, concatenation

In each table have many number of rows with amount. Like this i have different numbers of amount in each table.  Each tables field name is different.  How can i get the total of all values in the four tables in a single query?  Any way is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try something like this?

```
select sum(val) from (
    select sum(col1) as val from table1 where criteria1 = 'x'
    union all
    select sum(col2) from table2 where criteria2 = 'y'
    union all
    select sum(col3) from table3 where criteria3 = 'z'
    union all
    select sum(col4) from table4 where criteria4 = 'w'
) newTbl
```

Comment: In some databases the union command automatically removes duplicate rows.  This would be a problem if you get the same sum from two of the tables.  Use 'union all' to preserve duplicates.

Comment: I used this way, i got this type of error. 
#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias 
Y it is so ?  and one more thing 'union all' is working in mysql?

Comment: SELECT sum( val )
FROM (

SELECT sum( rtotal ) AS val
FROM W
WHERE rrdate = '2010-04-15'
AND active = '1'
UNION SELECT sum( ertotal )
FROM X
WHERE errdate = '2010-04-15'
AND active = '1'
UNION SELECT sum( crtotal )
FROM Y
WHERE crrdate = '2010-04-15'
AND active = '1'
UNION SELECT sum( iamount )
FROM Z
WHERE idate = '2010-04-15'
AND ifor = 'R'
)

MySQL said: Documentation
#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias 

This is the error i got

Answer (score 0):

use derived tables - u probably want to do something like this so you get all results in a single row !

```
select
  u.user_count,
  c.country_count
from
(
  select count(*) as user_count from users where username like 'f%'
) u
join
(
  select count(*) as country_count from country
) c;
```

a more comlpex example: http://pastie.org/921407